# Does every traversable monad have an accompanying sequence

Tags: scala, monads, scalaz

I was looking at `scalaz` and seeing that most monads have the ability to be [traversed](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/release/6.0.4/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Traverse.scala#L15) `List`, `Option`, `Identity` etc and wondering if that means that every traversable object can also have a sequence - [consider](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/release/6.0.4/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/MA.scala#L124).

If that is in fact the case (I could indeed be wrong), then what is the output of a `Identity` for example:

`Identity(Option(1))` would this become `Option(Identity(1))`? Or am I missing something, if that is the case any pointers would be extremely helpful.

**Edit**

Indeed I was correct about the identity sequence being the following:

`Identity(Option(1))` does indeed become `Option(Identity(1))`. So that part of the question is settled.

So my question is refined to the original title - is every traversable monad sequencable?

Comment: fyi: I know this is scalaz 6 release, it's the release I've looked at most.

Comment: Yes—and it doesn't even need to be a monad: anything traversable can be sequenced. Your second link shows `sequence` defined in terms of `traverse`, so how could it be any other way?

Comment: Don't know actually, removed it from the post.

Comment: @TravisBrown do you want to add your comment as reply so I can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sequence` can be very straightforwardly defined as traversal with the identity function—i.e. in Haskell:

```
sequence = traverse id
```

Or in Scalaz 6 (from your second link above), the considerably more verbose:

```
def sequence[N[_], B](implicit
  a: A <:< N[B],
  t: Traverse[M],
  n: Applicative[N]
): N[M[B]] = traverse((z: A) => (z: N[B]))
```

So yes, any type with a traversable instance can be sequenced (and it doesn't even need to be a monad).